# Animation scroll top 0 react native

Tags: react-native, animation

i'm trying to set the scrollView's value to be 0 and it's crashing

below is my code

```
 const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Animated.ScrollView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: scrollY}}}],
          {useNativeDriver: true},
        )}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}>
        <Animated.View style={{top: scrollY}}>
          <ProductDetail route={route} navigation={navigation} />
        </Animated.View>
        <ProductDetailInfo route={route} />
        <Topping route={route} />
      </Animated.ScrollView>
      <ButtonProductDetail />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to scroll to the top of the list, the `ScrollView` has a method for this, [`scrollTo()`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto). Following is an example of how to use it:

```js
import { useRef } from 'react'
import {
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

export default function ScrollToTopExample() {
  const listRef = useRef()

  const handleScrollToTop = () => {
    listRef.current.scrollTo({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      animated: true,
    })
  }

  const Button = () => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleScrollToTop} >
      <Text>Go to top</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )

  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView ref={listRef} >
        // Some content here
      </ScrollView>
      <Button />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I created a [snack on Expo](https://snack.expo.dev/@marcelofreires/stackoverflow-questions-75236398) for you to see the complete example on the computer with the source code. But the animation of the scroll works only on a mobile. You can scan the QR Code from your smartphone using the [Expo Go](https://expo.dev/client) app to see it in action.

[image: QR Code to see the full example on Expo Go app]